# in SBCL why does setting *print-circle* to T in LET in common lisp not work, but SETF does print circular list fine?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, circular-list, dynamic-scope

I noticed that if I setf `*print-circle*` to T, then it prints circular list:

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* t)
T
CL-USER> (let ((x (list 1)))
           (setf (cdr x) x)
            x)
#1=(1 . #1#)
```

But if I try using `let` instead to set `*print-circle*`, it hangs indefinitely.

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* nil)
NIL
CL-USER> (let ((*print-circle* t)
               (x (list 1)))
           (setf (cdr x) x)
            x)
;; hangs indefinitely
```

What gives? I thought `*print-circle*` was a special "dynamically binding" variable, and thus using `let` will be able to temporarily bind it?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the printing is only done by the REPL *after* the `let` is evaluated, in which case the temporary setting of `*print-circle*` is already gone.

To get the effect I'm looking for, I need to make sure the printing is done inside the let:

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* nil)
NIL
CL-USER> (let ((*print-circle* t)
               (x (list 1)))
           (setf (cdr x) x)
           (prin1 x)
           nil)
#1=(1 . #1#)
NIL
CL-USER>
```

Note that last `nil` after `(prin1 x)` is important, since without it, the repl will still attempt to evaluate then print the value of `(prin1 x)` outside the LET, and thus get stuck again